# SELECT FOR XML, How to use?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlxml

This statement below:

```
SELECT
    ....
FROM
    ....
WHERE
    ....
FOR XML PATH('Booking'), ROOT('doc')
```

This returns all the records in one XML string. I wish for each record to have its own XML string. Does this make sense? Is it possible. Does it make sense to do this?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want each row to produce a separate XML document (there is no such thing as an 'XML string'). You need to run *each* row through the FOR XML. For example, take each row from the table and use the [`CROSS APPLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) operator to project a single row `FOR XML TYPE`. Use a  row table value constructor for the join. Eg. using master..spt_values:

```
select t.*
 from master..spt_values s
 cross apply (
 select s.* 
 from (values (1) ) as t(c) 
 for xml path('Boookin'), root('Doc'), type) as t(x)
```

will return one XML document per row, with a structure like:

```
<Doc>
  <Boookin>
    <name>rpc</name>
    <number>1</number>
    <type>A  </type>
    <status>0</status>
  </Boookin>
</Doc>
```

Substitute master..spt_values with your table of choice.